# Kafka connect MongoDB sink connector date format

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I’m using Kafka connect Mongo-DB sink connector (persist messages from Kafka to Mongo).
The Kafka messages are simple JSON:

```
{"field":"value", "ttl": "1648022542"}
```

As you can see, I have a TTL field in each message.
I want to turn this TTL to persist in Mongo in a date format (I want this document to be deleted at this time and mongo can do it only on date formats and not timestamp).

Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly but if you want to transform your data while writing into mongodb, you can do it with connector configuration. Can you find something useful for your case here? https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/sink-connector/configuration-properties/post-processors/

Comment: I didn't find something for my specific use case @BünyaminŞentürk. I need to transform the timestamp into an ISO date format in mongo.

Comment: `TimestampConverter` transforms didn't help?

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you please provide a reference?

Comment: Docs https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/timestampconverter.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed to convert a String representation of Timestamp into a valid ISODate (a valid Timestamp that MongoDB can work with in filters and queries).

I am using Confluent Kafka v7.3.2 and MongoDB Sink Connector to which I added the TimestampConverter property mentioned above.

This is how my MongoSinkConnector properties file looks like (the relevant part of it):

```
name=<mongo-sink-name>
topics=<topic-name>
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

# Message types
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

# Specific global MongoDB Sink Connector configuration
connection.uri=<mongodb-address>
database=<database-name>
collection=<collection-name>

# Single Message Transform (SMT) to convert "TimeStamp" string to ISODate
transforms=TimestampToIsoDate
transforms.TimestampToIsoDate.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.TimestampToIsoDate.target.type=Timestamp
transforms.TimestampToIsoDate.field=TimeStamp
transforms.TimestampToIsoDate.format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS
```

So I think in your case you should specify *ttl* in transforms.TimestampToIsoDate.field and some numeric representation in transforms.TimestampToIsoDate.format